# Extract long from arbitrary bitset subsequence

Tags: c++, bitset

Is there a way to extract a CPU word size long subsequence of bits from a bitset efficiently without iterating over each bit individually? Something like

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        bitset<100> b;
        // Do something with b
        // ...

        // Now i want sizeof(long) many bits starting at position 50
        unsigned long l = (b>>50).to_ulong();
}
```

would do if it would truncate the bitstring instead of throwing an exception!

Comment: Its not clear. Give one example.

Comment: @Nawaz i hope this makes it more clear...

Comment: it would have been better if you give some input and ouput example.

Comment: Near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2177186/240633

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a constant bitset `mask` that only has the bottom N bits set, eg like this:

```
bitset<100> const mask((unsigned long) -1);
```

Then you can do `((b >> 50) & mask).to_ulong()` to extract the bits. If your definition of "word" isn't the same as unsigned long, a different mask will be needed.

(I changed your left shift to a right shift, which I believe will work better.)

A sufficiently smart compiler could convert this to just a shift and reading out the result; I doubt whether any compilers are actually sufficiently smart. But I suspect the cost of the shift outweighs the cost of the and anyway.

Comment: Oh my! Indeed the exception is only thrown if bits higher than sizeof(unsigned long) are set! I had concluded that the exception is thrown for every bitset<n> with n>sizeof(unsigned long). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

New info on comments make this answer irrelevant.

The answer needs a question: What basic datatype is your bitset made from?
Assuming the said bitset is stored lsb to msb on an lsB to msB array of unsigned chars, then:

1) the byte index holding bit X is found by X/8;

2) the bit index at byte (X/8), is found by X%8;

After X%8 -1 left shifting of that unsigned char you have the lsb of the resulting unsigned long and the next 8-X%8 bits. Because the shift operator operated on a single unsigned char, you'll need further code to copy to the next 3 (or 4) unsigned chars) into an auxiliary short/long, then or-copy to the result the relevant bits that will make the full unsigned long.

Comment: I am talking about std::bitset. That support the subscript [] operator, hence the arithmetic that you describe there is already implemented. I'm looking for a solution to extract a max. CPU word size long word with say at most 2 shift operations + AND internally (which would be possible i guess) - but i dont see that the std::bitset frontent supports that. using the subscript operator to do a bit-wise copy is not the solution i'm looking for, each [] call returns a bool.